# Missing dependency for application?

Tags: c++, sql-server

I have a very simple application which parses some text files and inserts the records into a SQL Server database.

"It works for me," but it crashes on the following line, when run on another machine:

```cpp
cmr->dateTimeStamp = TIMESTAMP_STRUCT { };
```

That, to me, means there's a missing dependency related to either TIMESTAMP_STRUCT, because that's the only thing on that line that hasn't appeared before then, in the program.

TIMESTAMP_STRUCT and SQLUSMALLINT are defined in sqltypes.h, and they're just typedefs, anyway, so I wouldn't expect there to be any dependencies there.

I've installed the SQL Server native client 11 and the visual C++ runtime on the target machine.

What else could I be missing?

Visual Studio 2015, and target machine is Windows Server 2008 R2.

I'm using the same input file on both machines, yet it only fails on one machine.

Comment: Is it not possible to break it down to pieces to figure out which piece causes issue? Is it possible to implement exception handling to capture error and exit the app more gracefully?

Comment: `cmr` is probably NULL from a previous error.  Find the error by installing the remote debugger (on the machine where the app is crashing) and debugging remotely from your development machine to the test/release machine.  FYI: for missing dependencies you will get a nice dialog telling you exactly what is missing.

Comment: Exceptions in C API many times have misleading descriptions. I use sometimes MFC layer, with such prblems. What exactly exception You have?

Comment: It's the same input file. And cmr isn't null (verified that). That's why I was suspecting a dependency problem between the two machines. I'll break down that struct assignment to see if it hates something specific about it, but that seems pretty darn unlikely since those are just ints.

Comment: Just tested. It's the creation of the struct that throws the error. It exits with exception code 1d, which MSDN says is ERROR_WRITE_FAULT, which makes zero sense to me in that context. I've edited the code sample to match what currently fails.

Comment: The issue is the allocation.  If I declare it without the `{ }`, it works fine apparently. Why can't I initialize this struct like that? Furthermore, why does it work on one machine but not another? Both are equivalent windows versions (2008 R2 and Win 7, both x64). To me, typedefs and structs shouldn't behave ANY differently from one machine to the next, when they're composed entirely of primitives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue came down to a compiler flag.

This project started as a toy application for something completely unrelated, that had AVX instructions in it.  The flag to target that instruction set was never un-set when it became a "real" application.

Removing that compiler flag (/arch:AVX) makes the program work on both machines.
What's strange to me is that there are no AVX instructions anyway, in this program, so why would the flag being set cause a difference in execution between two machines, especially for something so benign as initialization of a struct composed of primitive types?

Comment: How did you determine this? Did you look at the assy code?

Comment: Determine what, specifically?

Comment: The toy application had AVX instructions in it because I put them there. I was testing the impact it would have on a specific piece of code. How do I know the compiler flag affected the current application? Because I ran it once with the flag on and once with the flag off. How do I know there are no AVX instructions in the current application? Well, I guess I don't, if the compiler is opportunistically using them just because that flag is set. I don't see where and how it would have used one, though, and the assembly output from VS doesn't show any AVX instructions, so I'm at a loss.

Comment: Inserting AVX instructions in the source code is a compiler/cpu extension. OTOH, the /arch:AVX option enables the compiler to utilize the cpu's AVX instructions which may, or may not be generated when compiling.